# Could not find aaptcompiler-4.2.0.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I get the 1 error while syncing Gradle as below:
Could not find aaptcompiler-4.2.0.jar
Has anyone had a similar experience?
[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhRRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by changing Gradle version and turning on a proxy the problem of accessing the repository got solved.